# check if profile data exists on profile update

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have a profile page, function for the edit and a check function for the edit.

profile page:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit']) && $_POST['edit'] === 'Edit') {

    $errorMsgs = $user->validateUpdate($_POST);
    if (empty($errorMsgs)) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    $user->updateProfile($username,$email,$id);
    echo 'edited';
    exit;
    }
    foreach ($errorMsgs as $msg) {
        echo '<li>'. $msg. '</li>';
    }
}


      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>  
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
Username<br>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" /><br>
Email<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" /><br>
<input name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit"/>
</form>
 <?php }
        ?>
```

Update function:

```
 function updateProfile($username,$email,$id){
        $con = new Core();
        $con->connect();
        $username = trim(strtolower($username));
        $username = str_replace(' ', '', $username);
        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET username = ?, email = ? where id = ?';
        if ($stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sql))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $username, $email, $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else{
            die("errormessage: " . $con->myconn->error);
        }

    }
```

Check function:

```
function validateUpdate(array $userDetails)
    {
        $con = new Core();
        $con->connect();
        $errmsg_arr = array();
        foreach($userDetails as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                $errmsg_arr[] = ucwords($key) . " field is required";
            }
        }

        if (!empty($userDetails['edit'])) {
            if (!empty($userDetails['email']) && !filter_var($userDetails['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errmsg_arr[] = "the provided email is not a valid email address";
            }

            $sqlu = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
            if($stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sqlu)){
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
                $stmt->execute();

            }
            if($stmt->fetch() > 0){
                $errmsg_arr[] = "Username already exists!";
                $stmt->close();
            }

            $sqle = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?";
            if($stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sqle)){
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            if($stmt->fetch() > 0){
                $errmsg_arr[] = "Email already exists!";
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
        return $errmsg_arr;
    }
```

Everything works perfect. But there's a flaw in this check.

Someone goes to their profile.
The person tries to edit details, edits it all: code echo's "succesfully edited".

But if the person tries to edit Email only instead of all details, gets the error message that the "Username value" already exists.

Now my question: How would I let it not check on the username value if it isn't edited? Or email value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would exclude the user that's logged in from the query. While doing the login you would save the users id in a session variable. You can use this variable for preventing the queries from checking against the user itself

```
$sqlu = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND id != '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$sqle = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ? AND id != '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
```

That should fix your issue! [More info on session variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: This helped! I totally didn't think about it this way. Thank you!

Comment: No problem ^^ glad i could be of help! Good luck on the rest of your project, i'd be happy to help if encounter other issues. P.S. I just noticed you should probably add those session variables using the prepared statement as well (not concat it in like i did here), but i'm assuming you implemented it correctly already :)